# Why do Number class have an intValue() , even if the method implementation would be same across the subclasses, So what is the need of overriding it?

Tags: java, design-patterns, overriding

Why does [Number](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Number.html) Class have an abstract methods [intValue()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Number.html#intValue()),[longValue()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Number.html#longValue()) etc, even though Numbers are expected to return int or long etc? Why can't they have already implemented methods?

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking.

Answer (score 2):

That's because the implementation of the methods depends on the underlying subclass. For example you have to determine the `intValue()` of a `BigDecimal` or a `Double` differently than for an `Integer` because of dealing with floating point representation. So there is no way that the superclass can sum-up how to calculate these methods.

Comment: ohh! Yes. BigDecimal has different implementation for intValue().
Thank You @GHajba. I will look into it.

Answer (score 2):

Following are direct known subclasses of `Number`:

`AtomicInteger`, `AtomicLong`, `BigDecimal`, `BigInteger`, `Byte`, `Double`, `Float`, `Integer`, `Long`, `Short`.

So they should only decide what should be the corresponding int value.

Integer conversion logic for `BigDecimal` is definitely going to be different from integer conversion logic for `Double` (or `Byte` for that matter).

But yes they all should have a corresponding int value. Hence abstract method in `Number`

Comment: Thanks  @Raman.   I had completely missed to check BigDecimal and BigInteger class

Answer (score 0):

As the simple OOPS concept , they abstract out the more generalized features, given the options to the specialized classes(Sub-Classes) to give more specific implementation.